# How can it be sure that the $x$'s values are converging in the formal definition of a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, definition, epsilon-delta

In the $\delta,\epsilon$ definition of a limit :
$$ \forall \varepsilon > 0,\,\exists \ \delta > 0,\,\forall x \in D,\,0 < |x - c | < \delta \ \Rightarrow \ |f(x) - L|$$

why the condition $\delta(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0  $ if $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ is not specified? Is this condition implicit ? and is it necessary?

As far as I understand in this definition is written that when $\epsilon$ becomes smaller and smaller there's always a  $\delta$'s neighbourhood for which the distance between every $f(x)$ with $x\in$ $\delta$'s neighbourhood   and the limit $L$ is less than $\epsilon$ , but how can I be sure that this values of $x$ are converging to the value $c\,$  ( as it is called in the formal definition ) ? Should't be necessary something like the condition I mentioned? Or another condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition clearly emphasizes that the the inequality $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon $ should hold for **all** values of $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$. And all these values of $x$ include values of $x$ which are as close to $a$ as we please. A larger value of $\delta$ does not remove the set of values of $x$ which are near $a$. More formally if $0<\delta_1<\delta_2$ then the set of values of $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta_1$ is a subset of the set of values of $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta_2$.

Thus a large value of $\delta$ does not contradict your intuitive understanding of limit.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary. Take the null function $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. Hence $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$. But, if you want to prove this using the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition, you can, for each $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=1$. Actually, you can even take $\delta=\frac1\varepsilon$!

Comment: and if the function isn't constant?

Comment: If the function isn't constant it is still possible that $\delta$ doesn't have to be small when $\varepsilon$ is small.

Comment: @Peter Szilas This is a constant function

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I've not come across the term 'null function' before; is this $f(x)=x$?

Comment: No, that's the identity function. The null function is $f(x)=0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you. Confusingly a ['null function'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_function) in computer science seems to be an identity function.

Comment: No, the page you linked to says that a "null function" is a function that returns NO result, not that it returns x.

Comment: @user247327 Actually, what is written there is “Mathematically, a (computer) function $f$ is null if and only if its execution leaves the program state $s$ unchanged. That is, a null function is an identity function whose domain and codomain are both the state space $S$ of the program, and for which: 
$f(s)=s$ for all elements $s\in S$.”